# rails form_for submit to "save" or "add another"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a representation of a TrainingDrill that has many DrillSteps.

```
class Drill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :drillsteps
end

class DrillStep < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :drill
end
```

When creating a new Drill step I'd like to provide a "save" button and an "add another" button.

- Save - saves the drillstep and goes back to the originating Drill.
- Add Another - saves the drillstep and redisplays the New page to add
  another step.

The "save" is straight forward and working fine

```
%= form_for [@drill, @drill_step] do |f| %>
...
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

That routes back nicely to my controller and creates the new drillstep and back to my Drill like I want it to.

Any ideas on how to do an "add another" and get it to call my controller, save drillstep, and then redisplay the New page?

Thanks

Comment: An easy solution is to create a radio button/checkbox with those options, then filter them in your 'create' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in yur post activity. Example:

```
def recieved_params_for_drill
   begin
     @drill = Drill.create(params_for_drill)
     redirect_to  (YOUR ROUTE IN CONTROLLER FOR NEW ACTION)
   rescue => e
     puts e
   end
end
```

redirect_to  (YOUR ROUTE IN CONTROLLER FOR NEW ACTION)  => YOUR CHECK IN CONSOLE with rake route command and get a rout for new drill

regards!